# Best way to do multiple pagination on one page in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, pagination

I have seen a number of old posts around this topic on stack overflow but none of them seem to give any clarity. What I have understood by going through them is that codeigniter doesnt support multiple paginations through its class and that you have to write your own class.

I wonder if that is the case. In case any body here has an idea about how to do it please let me know. I have three lists which I'm passing into the view. However when I paginate all of them, all the three lists response to same page offset. Is Ajax_pagination the way out?

Please suggest how to do this.

UPDATE: Here is my code and what I'm trying to do.This is a view file. I have two lists 1. org_list 2. Ind_list
I'm trying to pass to these two lists in tow view files (organization_listing, individual_listing) both of which are loaded in this view file and therefore appear on the same page. Now I can paginate one list but when I paginate the second file they both respond to same uri offset.

I'm generating the pagination links in the (organization_listing, individual_listing) view files.

```
<?php 

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/socialinew/user_registration/index.php/members_area/view_members_area';
    $config['total_rows'] = count($org_list);
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination3">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    for($i=$this->uri->segment(3)+0;$i<(($this->uri->segment(3)+$config['per_page']));$i++)
    {
        if(isset($org_list[$i]))
        {$temp_org[$i]=$org_list[$i];
        }


    }

    $tmp_org['org_list']=$temp_org;


$this->load->view('organization/organization_listing',$tmp_org);



    $org_config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/socialinew/user_registration/index.php/members_area/view_members_area/';
    $org_config['total_rows'] = count($ind_list);
    $org_config['per_page'] = 5;
    $org_config['num_links'] = 20;
    $org_config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination2">';
    $org_config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($org_config);

    for($i=$this->uri->segment(4)+0;$i<(($this->uri->segment(4)+$config['per_page']));$i++)
    {
        if(isset($ind_list[$i]))
        {$temp_ind[$i]=$ind_list[$i];
        }
    }

        $tmp_ind['ind_list']= $temp_ind;
```

$this->load->view('individual_listing',$tmp_ind);?>

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you do not like ajax ... you can use iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I have finally used javascript to load my individual paginations into the page, so I'm sending my paginations into three different views and then using javascript to call those views into the page. Couldnt figure out any way to do multiple paginations on the same page.

Comment: Guys I had asked this question over an year ago, since then working with codeigniniter, javascript I have realised that your options are severely restricted if your use the codeigniter's pagination. Its built for very basic use and you'd bump into some restriction as you try to cusomize it for your own purposes. Instead if you could build your own javascript ajax calls to build your own paginations, you'd be able to build more functionalities.

Comment: any idea how? im also having a problem with that.. help.

Comment: @Vincent in case you're ok/cofortable with jquery-ajax calls, you could use that for pagination. You could load your records in controller and send ajax calls from frontend with parameters specifying the range of records you want to pull into front end. An year ago when I had asked the question, I was not comfortable with ajax and so was looking forward to codeigniter's native functionality to work. But as it turned out jquiery/ajax is a much better method to do this.

Comment: uhmmm im just new in ajax and jquery . :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want

```
1 2 3 4

 results

1 2 3 4

 results
```

I'm fairly certain it's pretty straight forward:

1. just configure for the first set (say to use uri segment 3)
2. Initialize the pagination
3. Create the links; and
4. Send it to the view.

Then

1. Configure for the second set (say to use uri segment 4)
2. Initialize the pagination
3. Create the links; and
4. Send it to the view.

Comment: How to set the base url in that case?

Comment: you can't set it with `$config['base_url']`? and use `$config['uri_segment'] = <number>;` to tell what segment is meaningful to change.  Look at the docs on url helper to help with setting the base.

Comment: yes i have set the first pagination to look for uri segment 3 and the second pagination for uri segment 4. But I cant figure out how to pass a wildcard in $config[base_url] for the third uri segment. Also went through url helper but cant see what there can help me. may be missed something.

Comment: Can you just build it from the current uri segments?

Comment: I tried building it using the current uri segment, but for the first page the page offset is empty i.e. baseurl/ and it becomes 5 for second page i.e. baseurl/5. Now when the offset is empty, my second pagination when clicked creates an offset like baseurl/5, when it shud hv been baseurl/offset from pagination 1/5. Sooverall it works weirdly.